# XPath to select label plus hidden radio button option using WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

I am unable to write the correct XPath to select the title "MRS" for below code. I am using below code, but unable to execute it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@value='MRS']")).click();
```

Getting below error message :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@value='MRS']"}

```
<div class="question-group">

    <label class="on">Mr</label>
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="MR" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

    <label class="off">Mrs</label>
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="MRS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

    <label class="off">Miss</label>
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="MISS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

    <label class="off">Ms</label>
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="MS" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

    <label class="off">Dr</label>
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="DR" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">

    <label class="off">Rev</label>
    <input type="radio" name="title" value="REV" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" style="display:none" name="otherTitle" value="" placeholder="Other title:" id="otherTitle">

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Syntax in what? Syntax in Xpath? Also, where is the ending tag for your leading `div`? That will make it hard for anyone to help you as well.

Comment: yes in xpath and i have pasted complete xml. there is nothing missing

Comment: i have added screenshot as well

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code you have tried and the results you got.

Comment: Hi Kate,I have added the code and error message in above question.

Comment: @Arjun Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Comment: using java in selenium

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a little bit from your code and the screen shot you provided: the radio buttons are hidden and the user is actually clicking the formatted labels instead, right?

In this case your problem is that Selenium / WebDriver interacts with visible objects only. So you simply cannot click any radio button - because there is none. You have to click the labels.

Try `.//div[@class='question-group']/label[text()='Mrs']` as xpath expression.

Comment: used below code and getting error message    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/label[text()='Mrs']")).click();

Comment: I created a little test with the code fragement you provided above and the xpath expression is working and selects the appropriate label. Thus I think something different beside the xpath must create your problem. Please use `driver.getPageSource()` to log what the driver "is seeing" when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is any `<div>` tag in your page do no have attribute `value="MRS"` that's why it throwing error `NoSuchElementException`

try with below xpath:

```
//div[@class='question-group']/input[@value='MRS']
```

or CSS

```
div[class='question-group']>input[value='MRS']
```

Comment: tried below code and still showing error driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@value='MRS']")).click();

Comment: error message Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='question-group']/input[@value='MRS']"}

Comment: try `//div[@class='question-container']//div[class='question-group']/label[text()='Mrs']`  or just debug by placing `Thread.sleep(3000)` before you click

Comment: tried below code and still not worksThread.sleep(5000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-container']//div[class='question-group']/label[text()='Mrs']")).click();

Comment: is there any iframe ?

Comment: No. Other text fields are entered. for title i am unable to click it

Comment: tried css selector still not works driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='question-group']>input[value='MRS']")).click();

Comment: for javascript can you please send write full code

Comment: tried below stil not works      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/input[@value='MRS']"));

  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: tried one more code as well, but it is not working as well                                               driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='question-group label:nth-child(5)']")).click();

Comment: Hi Narendra, any update on above code?

Comment: Hi Narendra, can you please provide code for below link               https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/36496/35535

Comment: @Arjun, if any answer is helpful for you then accept it if not then post the work around done by you as an answer if you think that is a solution. still have question then update the content. thanks

Comment: Hi Narendra, the above question is still pending and i tried all the above codes and still i am getting error to select title.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to try here. 
If you are trying to target the input element, then

XPATH:

```
.//*[@value='MRS']
```

or CSS:

```
[value='MRS']
```

should work.

Comment: Tried with xpath  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='MRS']")).click();           and got error message

Comment: tried with Css as well  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='MRS']")).click();           got error message

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided to invoke `click()` on the element related to the title **MRS** as the element is having the `clearfix` class, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-controls clearfix']/div[@class='question-group']//label[contains(.,'Mrs')]//following::input[1]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: still getting error with above code

Comment: Can you update the main question with the exact _error trace logs_ for further analysis?

Comment: error message     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[@class='question-controls clearfix']/div[@class='question-group']//label[contains(.,'Mrs')]//following::input[1] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, the radio button is hidden so no point trying to click on it. 
Instead try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='question-group']/label[text()='Mrs']")).click();
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: No it did not worked